# How to visualize layers from ArcGIS\QGIS project in their order

Tags: qgis, arcmap, layers, visualisation, tools

A lot of times I've seen visualization of layer in their order (like on the pic). Could anyone recommend a tool to make the same with my layers (could be QGIS or ArcGIS) or at least how this visualization is called?

[image]

Comment: May be you start here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/introducing_gis.html or here https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/introGIS.html ....there are more resources out there. just google

Comment: You have ArcGIS in your title, QGIS in the tags, and "QGIS or ArcGIS" in the body -- This will often result in closure for lack of focus. Please choose one software stack per question to conform to the One question per Question policy emphasized by the [Tour].

Comment: edited title and tags

Comment: @belunarch was pretty clear with the question, I don't see what the problem is, so you're pointing it to some pages? You can do something similar in Golden Surfer software, but not quite like that. And I've been asking for it for a long time.